# i am trying to login inputty through ec2 instance public ip but it is not allowing me to login

Tags: passwords

putty is not opening with public ip adress.
denyin the password after logined as root.so that,i am unable to continue to do my aws regular work.

i tried to open putty with ubuntu configration,  and i gave defaut host ip address.Now,putty opens but asking for login user name,and password.i logined as root and gave password which i set in ubuntu configuration,but i am trying from last 5days ,putty constantly refusing password.what password or which password should i give to continue my work in putty as regular.is there any format for password or ssh connection?